# How to change width of wizard popup window?

Tags: odoo, popup, odoo-14

Is there a way to make the wizard popup window AND its content wider than the default size?

I need to change the selected single popup not all.

[image]

I have simple wizard form with tree view added in notebook page. My problem is, that the tree has quite a few fields and the window is not wide enough to display them all properly.

I have tried using `<script>` tags inside the form and even managed to make the window wider, but the tree remained the same thus defeating the purpose.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.modal-dialog').css({'max-width': '70%'});
        $('.modal-content').css({'max-width': '100%'});
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Web Dialog Size](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/14.0/web_dialog_size/) module to expand/restore the dialog box size through a button in the upper right corner

Comment: Anyone know Why it is not available for the version 13 ?

Comment: You can find it on [Github](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/13.0/web_dialog_size)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. A combination of `<script>` showed in question and adding style="width:110%;" to one2many field used as the tree did the trick. It is probably not the cleanest solution but it does what I need. Although the best solution would be if the window widened automatically according to the tree view.

Comment: It is a little bit weird, that I can post an answer for my own question but I can't mark it as a solution or upvote it.